# AcquireCredentialsHandleW failing

Tags: c, winapi

I have a piece of code that attempts to acquire the credentials for a user on a remote computer which I cant get working. currently this produces an access violation error (0xc0000005) when run:

```
SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W identity;
ZeroMemory(&identity, sizeof(identity));

identity.Domain = (unsigned short *)_T("DOMAIN");
identity.DomainLength = lstrlenW(_T("DOMAIN"));
identity.User = (unsigned short *)_T("USER");
identity.UserLength = lstrlenW(_T("USER"));
identity.Password = (unsigned short *)_T("PASS");
identity.PasswordLength = lstrlenW(_T("PASS"));
identity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;

PCredHandle credentials = NULL;
PTimeStamp credentialsExpiry = NULL;

SECURITY_STATUS result = AcquireCredentialsHandleW(_T("USER"), _T("NTLM"), SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL, &identity, NULL, NULL, credentials, credentialsExpiry);
```

and i have no idea why. any assistance would be very welcome.

Comment: AcquireCredentialsHandle will not allocate space for credentials, shouldnt have NULLed the credentials and credentialsExpiry structures ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the last section of code to look like this:

```
CredHandle credentials;
TimeStamp credentialsExpiry;

SECURITY_STATUS result = AcquireCredentialsHandleW(_T("USER"), _T("NTLM"), 
    SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, NULL, &identity, NULL, NULL, 
    &credentials, &credentialsExpiry);
```

Per [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374712(VS.85).aspx), the pointers in the last 2 parameters are not optional on your call:

> **phCredential [out]**
>
> A pointer to a
> CredHandle structure to receive the
> credential handle.
>
> **ptsExpiry [out]**
>
> A pointer to a
> TimeStamp structure that receives the
> time at which the returned credentials
> expire. The value returned in this
> TimeStamp structure depends on the
> security package. The security package
> must return this value in local time.
>
> This parameter is set to a constant
> maximum time. There is no expiration
> time for Digest security contexts or
> credentials or when using the Digest
> SSP.
>
> When using the Schannel SSP, this
> parameter is optional. When the
> credential to be used for
> authentication is a certificate, this
> parameter receives the expiration time
> for that certificate. If no
> certificate was supplied, then a
> maximum time value is returned.